# Powershell catch-unknown handler

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to override/chain a handler that is then called whenever the shell would otherwise output the error that a inputted command/cmdlet is unknown/not found.

Comment: please add an example of what you are trying to acheive, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.CommandNotFoundAction = { <# do something #> }`